# Django queryset for many-to-many field with intermediate table

Tags: django, django-models

Here's my setup

Models

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Game(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through="GameTeams")
    game_heading = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

class GameTeams(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, blank=True)
```

How do I get all the (game, team) pairs associated with a particular league?  This is what I tried:

```
league = League.objects.get(pk=1) #This obviously works
league.game_set.gameteams_set.all() #This doesn't work
```

The resultant set should be something something along these lines:

```
league_id | game_id | team_id
1         | 1       | 1
1         | 1       | 2
1         | 1       | 3
1         | 2       | 2
1         | 2       | NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
league = League.objects.get(pk=1)
gameteams = GameTeams.objects.filter(game__league=league, team__league=league)
```

Comment: This was helpful.  Reducing it to `gameteams = GameTeams.objects.filter(game__league=league)` gave the result I was looking for.